# ¿Cuál es la diferencia poética entre ser cansado y estar cansado?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, poesía

En las líneas poéticas

***¡Que me lleve el mar!***

***Soy cansado de tanto querer***

cual sería la diferencia posible e implicaciones emocionales entre *soy cansado* y *estoy cansado* excepto que el ritmo sería diferente en cado caso?

Los otros ejémplos tienen la estructura del tipo ***cansado + de + verbo*** sin pronombres personales ni, en algunos casos, los verbos.

***cansado de mirar***

***en la tristeza de tus ojos*** (Andres Cabas)

***cansado de mirar de lejos (Eugenia Perez)***

***estoy cansado de sentir los muertos*** (Jaguares)

A veces encuentro estructuras del tipo ***ser cansado de hacer***, pero en los otros modos, tiempos o personas:

***Si eres cansado de intentar encontrar lo que deseas...***

***Él fue cansado de crear el mundo..***.

Comment: @mdewey I checked Manjusri's profile and I think he understands perfectly the differences between _ser_ and _estar_ and I think that is why the question refers to **diferencia poética**. Impressive profile btw. It usually helps to see "who is asking" to get an idea of the kind of answers he is looking for.

Comment: @DGaleano it was intended as a request for clarification and was not intended to be disrespectful. I have deleted it.

Comment: @mdewey I never say it was disrespectful and it was not. You have never been disrespectful in anyway in this forum. What I usually do before answering is to check the profile of the OP. That told me in this case that he knows lots of languages and he consider himself fluent in Spanish and I just wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 5):

"cansado", al igual que otros adjetivos que refieren a un estado temporario, no permanente, se utiliza con "estar", no con "ser".

Existen adjetivos -- pero no creo que sea el caso de "cansado" -- que pueden aludir, según se use "ser" o "estar", a un estado permanente o transitorio:

- Soy alegre (soy de temperamento alegre).
- Estoy alegre (por una situación en particular).

En el caso de "ser cansado", creo que estamos frente a una licencia poética, que transgrede en cierto modo las normas de la gramaticalidad o de la idiomaticidad, puesto que se utiliza la voz pasiva de "cansar" (cosa nada habitual en la lengua española). Mi interpretación es que esa oración significa:

- Tanto querer me cansa > Soy cansado por el hecho de querer tanto -> Soy cansado de tanto querer.

Comment: De acuerdo.  Yo lo leí más como si tuviese *por* en vez de *de*, puede que sea licencia poética o bien confusión entre la preposición correcta (la voz pasiva usa siempre *por*, pero *cansado* como adjetivo normalmente toma *de* o *con*)

Comment: @guifa Acabo de encontrar este otro post de Manjusri de donde se desprende que los versos provienen de una supuesta traducción plagada de errores: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20646/la-cualidad-po%C3%A9tica-y-el-origen-del-texto-siguiente. Dicho esto, mi respuesta carece de sentido, puesto que la elaboré sobre la falsa presunción de que se trataba de un texto correcto.

Comment: He añadido más ejemplos con las estructuras del tipo 'cansado de hacer'  y hasta 'ser cansado de hacer', pero la questión no se hizo más clara

Comment: @Manjusri Nadie objeta el uso de "de + infinitivo" después de "cansado". La cuestión aquí es si "ser cansado" es correcto. Los ejemplos que diste (incluido el primero del supuesto poema) NO son gramaticales. Sólo el último sería válido si "fue" es el pasado de "ir", no el pasado de "ser", pero usaría una coma antes de "cansado": *El fue (a algún lugar), cansado de crear el mundo*. Las oraciones correctas serían: Si **estás** cansado de intentar encontrar lo que deseas... / Él **se cansó** de crear el mundo (o **quedó cansado** después de crear el mundo).

Comment: @Gustavson Los ambos ejemplos son los dichos por personas  hispanoablantes y siguen utilisados con *ser*. Por eso concluyo que no deben despreciar su respuesta, pues en el texto se trata de un estado permanente y de una licencia poética

Comment: @Manjusri Gracias por tu apoyo, pero prefiero ser objetivo aunque sea en detrimento de una respuesta propia: podría asegurarte que las tres oraciones con "ser + cansado" no fueron ni serían dichas ni escritas por ningún hablante nativo del español. Si el poema sólo contuviera esa anomalía, podríamos hablar -- como lo hice en mi respuesta -- de una licencia poética. No obstante, habiendo leído el poema completo, advierto que se trata de uno de los tantos errores que el texto posee.

Comment: Igual, entre esta respuesta y los comentarios aclaran la situación (licencia poética vs error). Manjusri debería marcar esta respuesta como correcta.

Comment: @DGaleano En ese caso, sería mejor que Gustavson incorporase a la respuesta las consideraciones que luego hace en comentarios. En mi opinión, lo adecuado es que la respuesta sea completa para que sea útil a quienes vengan aquí en el futuro, sin necesidad de leerse todos los comentarios.